# Laravel check hasMany of hasMany relationship if has IDs?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-8

Hello I have the following relationship setup:

Product class:

```
public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class);
    }
```

ProductAttribute class:

```
public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttributeValue::class, 'product_attribute_id');
    }
```

ProductAttributeValue class:

```
public function attributeValue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AttributeValue::class, 'attribute_value_id');
    }
```

How to check if `Product` has `values` with ids `5` and `15`?

I am trying to make a query like this:

```
Product::whereHas('values', function($q) use ($product_values_ids) {
                    $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $product_values_ids);
                })->get();
```

however it is not working. I cannot access directly `$product->values`.

Any suggestions on how to access directly the values of attributes from the `Product`?

**Update:**

I have just managed to make it work with a many to many trough relationship:

Product class:

```
public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ProductAttributeValue::class, ProductAttribute::class);
    }
```

is there a way to get only the results that have all the ids listed in the `$product_values_ids` array?

Comment: you are checking if any products exist at all that have values with those ids, or you want those records matching that condition?  Product doesn't have a `values` relationship

Comment: I want to get all products that have values form the `$product_values_ids` array.

Comment: did you try a nested `whereHas`   `Product::whereHas('attributes.values', ...)->get();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new relation to Product model:

```
public function values(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ProductAttributeValue::class, ProductAttribute::class);
}
```

and then:

```
$builder = Product::query();
foreach($product_values_ids as $id) {
    $builder->whereHas('values', function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    });
}

$product = $builder->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just managed to do it exactly like this. One question left, at the moment with this `$q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $product_values_ids);` I am getting results, how can I get results only if they have all the `$product_values_ids` ? 

For example if the product_values_ids are [3, 12, 20] only return results that have all three of the ids, and if a product has values with id 3 and 12 to be left out?

Comment: You have not to use `whereIn`. I propose to replace `$q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $product_values_ids);` with  loop and `whereHas` and  `$q->where('id', $id);. It will return values only if all conditions work

Comment: Good suggestion, but when I do ```$results = $results->whereHas('values', function($q) use ($product_values_ids) {foreach ($product_values_ids as $id){$q->where('attribute_value_id', $id);} });``` I am not getting results based on two values

Comment: Try to clarify. Product has 3 attributes, every attribute has 3 values. Product ids we need: `[1,2]`.  The first variant: one attribute has value 1, second 2, third 3. Product has 1,2,3 and it appropriate for us. The second variant: one attribute has values [1,2], second 3, third 4. Product has 1,2,3, 4 and attribyte has [1,2] and it appropriate for us.
Which variant is right?

Comment: In order to clarify the goal is to "filter" all the products that have all the values provided by the `$product_values_ids`. If a product has only one of the provided values, it should not be fetched. If a product has all the array ids, it should be fetched.

Just tried out the second and the third variant, if there is only one array id, it works well, but when there are more than 1 provided ids, in the `$product_values_ids` it is not returning anything.

Comment: By the way, If I don't remove the inside `->get();` I am getting `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_attributes.id'`

Comment: Ok, I think it better to use the first approach with additional relation and loop with `$q->where('id', $id);` inside

Comment: Yes, I will use the first approach and will try to figure out how to match all the ids of the array and return the correct results.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you very much! I appreciate all the help.